# Use lottie library with webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, lottie

I came across a problem using Lottie for the first time in my webpack project.

As I usually do, i put the script tag with the Lottie src path at the end of the body tag, but this resulted in an error in the console: bodymovin is not defined at...

I think it's because I'm using webpack, that the Lottie script is loaded in after my index.js?
I'm not really sure where i should put my script tag then.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button class="button">Press me to light led</button>

    <p class="potentiometer"></p>
    <div class="bm"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.9/lottie.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const init = () => {
    const bm = document.querySelector('.bm');
    const anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: bm,
      path: `../assets/eye.json`,
      renderer: 'canvas',
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true
    })
```